# Distances in google sheets

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a set of 20,000 addresses and I need to find the distance between those and a set address.
The program works but I keep encountering the "service invoked too many times in one day" error message. Does anyone know if there is a way to buy more "queries" from google?

Thanks!

Code I am using:

```
function DrivingMeters(origin, destination) {
  var randnumber = Math.random()*10000;
      Utilities.sleep(randnumber);
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function DrivingMiles(origin, destination) {
  return DrivingMeters(origin, destination)/1609.34;  
}

function DrivingSeconds(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;  
}

function DrivingHours(origin, destination) {
  return DrivingSeconds(origin, destination)/(60*60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by referring to "queries", you mean "quota". Different services have different daily quotas. A possible exception message is:

> `Service invoked too many times: Calendar.` This indicates that the script called the given service too many times in one day.

for a normal consumer (gmail.com), this line is notable:

> URL Fetch calls:   20,000 / day

(see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) for all the documentation)

After doing a google search for "buy more apps script quota", there were no promising results. some workarounds suggested using other frameworks or splitting up quota from multiple users. My suggestion would be to look into upgrading from the "Consumer" level to the "Google Apps for Your Domain" level (or higher).

p.s. some sample code in your question may help, so we can narrow down which service you are trying to use, and if there are any possible ways to make your code more efficient.

Comment: Hey thanks for the responses. So I attempted to activate the "billing" option that would create a pay-as-you go system for the API. I activated it for the project I made in google spreadsheets. However, I am still experiencing the "service invoked too many times" error even though I activated billing. I attached the code to my original question.

Comment: how did you activate billing? was it by upgrading to Google Apps For Your Domain? If so, I found a note on the page: "Note: Newly created Google Apps domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer uses. For more information, see the Help Center page on sending limits.". this means you might have to wait a couple billing cycles, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting it correctly.

Comment: But it looks like this relates to sending a number of emails rather than a google maps API. Here is the link to the page I enabled "billing" on. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: you're right, I think I've been looking at the wrong docs. [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/usage-limits#maps-javascript-api-services-client-side) are the correct docs for the maps API. I think you will find something if you search around a bit